# PostgreSQL - query for record that is either side of the result set

Tags: postgresql

Lets say I have this table (`balances`) schema and data:

```
+----+---------+------------+
| id | balance | createdAt  |
+----+---------+------------+
|  1 |      10 | 2021-11-18 |
|  2 |      12 | 2021-11-16 |
|  3 |       6 | 2021-11-04 |
+----+---------+------------+
```

To retrieve the last 7 days of balances, I would do something like this:

`SELECT * FROM "balances" WHERE "createdAt" BETWEEN '2021-11-19T09:04:17.488Z' AND '2021-11-12T10:04:17.488Z' ORDER BY "createdAt" ASC`

This will give me 2 records (IDs: 1 & 2), which is fine. However, what I'm looking at doing, probably with a second query, is to grab the record that is previous to that result set, by `createdAt` date, as my query is ordered by `createdAt`. Is there a way to do this with PG?

So whatever the time-range I use, I would also retrieve the record that is n-1 to the result set

Comment: What is there be 2 or more records which are tied as being the immediately preceding records to the result set?  How do you want to handle this edge case?

Comment: if the query is sorted by `createdAt`, then is that possible?

(in my real table, the `createdAt` column is a full timestamp, so exact matches of value is extremely unlikely)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain the record you want, you may use a `LIMIT` query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM balances
WHERE createdAt < '2021-11-19T09:04:17.488Z'
ORDER BY createdAt DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This answer makes an assumption that there is only one record which is logically earlier than `2021-11-19T09:04:17.488Z`, and there is no edge case of ties.  If there are ties, we can break them by adding more levels to the `ORDER BY` clause.